# How to display blank spaces correctly while writing to a listbox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I am reading a file and printing to a list box in .While writing to the list box, the items are not properly aligned and spaces are also not formatted correctly. When I try to print it using **console. WriteLine ** method, the output is displaying exactly the same format as that of the input file.

Is there any standard way to handle the spaces and alignment while writing to a list box in c#.net?

Comment: Listbox of which framework. And what whitespaces? All or certain ones. You tags this with tabs.

Comment: I am using .NET framework and yes the tab spaces are not properly executing while printing.

Comment: That was not the framework i meant. I meant the framework creating the UI. Are you talking about a listbox from Winforms,WPF,Webforms or whatever?

Comment: Okay.. I am using Winforms

Comment: Tabs should work out of the box in Winforms but you may have changed [UseTabStops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.usetabstops?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Alignment beyond that might be a problem with the chosen font. You a comparing with the console output and a console uses a monospaced font typically (every character has the same width) and the standard fonts used in Winforms are not.

Comment: I changed font to monospace(courier New)...That resolved the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monospace font resolved the issue. I changed the font from sans-serif to courier new and everything looks perfect.

Thnaks to Ralf.